# Generic way of making CSS work on IE only without separate CSS sheet

Tags: css, internet-explorer, if-statement

I was just wondering about CSS for IE.  Typically we have a separate style sheet and  but I wondered if there was any way of incorporating different options in the **same** sheet, e.g.:

```
h1 {
    /* font size for Firefox to be 22px */
    font-size: 22px;
    /* font size for Internet Explorer to be 20px */
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

I.e. my question is it it possible to have all the options in one CSS sheet with conditions.

Comment: Check out the "Hacks" heading of [this page](http://css-tricks.com/132-how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/).

Comment: @BradChristie: +1 great resource

Comment: @BradChristie: +1 many thanks, that's exactly what I wanted!

Comment: @OuterbridgeMike: You're welcome. Posted it as an answer now that I know it was what you were looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just so it's posted as an answer (wasn't 100% sure it's what you wanted)...

Check out http://css-tricks.com/132-how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/ and look beneith the **Hacks** heading for in-line styles that are applicable only to specific IE versions. e.g.

**IE 6 only**

```
* html #div {
    height: 300px;
}
```

**IE 7 only**

```
*+html #div {
    height: 300px;
}
```

**IE 8 only**

```
#div {
  height: 300px\0/;
}
```

**IE 7 & 8 Only**

```
#div {
  height: 300px\9;
}
```

**Non-IE 7 Only**

```
#div {
   _height: 300px;
}
```

**Hide from IE6 & Lower**

```
#div {
   height/**/: 300px;
}

html > body #div {
      height: 300px;
}
```

*Quoted for reference and redundancy (in case the link breaks in the future).*

Answer (score 0):

You can use these hacks http://dimox.net/personal-css-hacks-for-ie6-ie7-ie8/

Answer (score -2):

If you want to run some server-side code, you should use a CSS Preprocessor such as [LESS](http://lesscss.org/).

Comment: I was un-aware this could be done in-line, considering `<!--` and `-->` aren't syntactically correct (valid tokens) in a CSS file.

Comment: -1: Conditional comments are meant to be used in HTML/XHTML documents only. They do not work in CSS documents (any browser will read and interpret the `font-size: 20px;` properly and ignore the lines with the conditionals). Also, they must be used outside of `<style>` tags in HTML/XHTML documents, making your example completely wrong in all scenarios.

Comment: conditional comments can only be used in html not in a css file

Comment: Those tags (<!--[if IE]>) are only for html but not for css. I guess.

Comment: Sorry, for all that confusion. Added clarification in the answer, plus an alternative of using a CSS preprocessor.

Comment: @Kibbee: Your example is still completely wrong. You cannot use conditional comments in tags that negate the HTML/XHTML tag workflow (`<style>`, `<script>`).

Comment: Yeah, took all that conditional comments stuff out.  Realized it probably wouldn't work at all for this situation.